# What is the fieldset id attribute and difference to value attribute?

Tags: html, forms, radio-button, fieldset

I'm learning HTML forms and saw some html `fieldset` with an `id`-attribute, but could not find any documentation or description when to use `id`  ( https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_fieldset.asp ) and the difference to `value` attribute. 
Example:

```
<form> 
   <p>Please select:</p> 
   <fieldset> 
     <input type="radio" id="mc" name="Payment Method" value="Mastercard">
        <label for="mc"> Mastercard</label> 
     <input type="radio" id="vi" name="Payment Method" value="Visa">  
        <label for="vi"> Visa</label> 
     <input type="radio" id="ae" name="Payment Method" value="AmericanExpress"> 
        <label for="ae"> American Express</label> 
   </fieldset> 
</form>
```

Could not find documentation for `id`-Tag and what is the difference between `id`-Tag and `value`- Tag?

Answer (score 1):

`id` attribute is used to identify a `html` tag. But the `value` attribute is used to set the "*value*" of the tags.

The "`value`" value is will be send to your server if you're using any back-end programming language.

```
<input type="radio" id="mc" name="Payment_Method" value="Mastercard">
<label for="mc"> Mastercard</label>
```

Using id in form helps focusing the input field when you click on his label

try the example below :

```css
*
  {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
  }
  body
  {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100vh;
  }

  p
  {
   width: 70%;
   margin: 2% auto;
   padding: .5%;
  }

  form
  {
   width: 50%;
   margin: 2% auto;
   padding: 1%;
  }

  label,
  input
  {
   display: block;
   width: 70%;
   margin: 1% auto;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>ID and Value</title>
 
</head>
<body>
 <p>
  Click on labels to see what will happen
 </p>
 <form action="#" method="post">
  <label for="third">Third</label>
  <input type="text" name="" id="first">

  <label for="fourth">Fourth</label>  
  <input type="text" name="" id="second">

  <label for="first">First</label>
  <input type="text" name="" id="third">

  <label for="third">Second</label>
  <input type="text" name="" id="fourth">
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I added some `CSS` to make it "beautyfull"

Hope it will help you !

Answer (score 0):

Use `id` attribute to refer to the element (in CSS, JavaScript, ..., or in the `for` attribute of `<label>`...).
The `value` attribute specifies the value to be sent in the HTTP request upon submission.

Answer (score 0):

The [id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) [global attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes) defines a unique identifier (ID) which must be unique in the whole document (Only one element per ID). Its purpose is to identify the element when linking (using a fragment identifier), scripting, or styling (with CSS).

Check and run the following **Code Snippet** for a practical example of how you can use the ID to reference elements in JavaScript:

```js
document.getElementById("blueColor").style.color = "blue";
document.getElementById("redColor").style.color = "red";
document.getElementById("greenColor").style.color = "green";
```

```html
<button id="blueColor">My ID is blue</button>
<button id="redColor">My ID is red</button>
<button id="greenColor">My ID is green</button>
<button id="redColor">Oh no!! My ID is a duplicate so it won't work!!</button>
```

---

The `value` attribute however is used for defining a default value which will be displayed in the element on page load. The `value` attribute can be used with the following elements: `<input>`, `<button>`, `<meter>`, `<li>`, `<option>`, `<progress>` and `<param>`.

- When present in “button”, “reset” and “submit”, it specifies the text on the button.
- When present in input “text”, input “password” and input “hidden”, it specifies the initial value of the input field.
- When present in input “checkbox”, input “radio” and input “image”, it specifies the value associated with the input.

Check and run the following **Code Snippet** for a practical example of how you can use the `value` attribute to retrieve default values as well as modified values in JavaScript:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("buttonID");

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name");
  var mail = document.getElementById("mail");
  var message = document.getElementById("msg");
  var uType = document.getElementById("userType");
  
  alert("Hello " + name.value + "! " + "Your email id is: " + mail.value + " your user type is: " + uType.value + " and your message is: " + message.value);
});
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name" />
</div>
<div>
  <label for="userType">User Type:</label>
  <input type="text" id="userType" name="user_type" value="Client" disabled/>
</div>
<div>
  <label for="mail">E-mail:</label>
  <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_email" />
</div>
<div>
  <label for="msg">Message:</label>
  <textarea id="msg" name="user_message"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="buttonID">Click Me</button>
</div>
```